# Algorithms for compare string in string and interger with constant integer

Tags: python

I have an if conditional return True like this:

```
if (('pro' in application_id) and (main_service_id != 102)) or  (('pro' not in application_id) and (main_service_id == 102)):
   return True
```

`application_id` can be any string and `main_service_id` is integer.

My question is : Is there a way to make `if` shorter while keeping the same logic?

Comment: You might want check this: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BlackThunder Not sure OP wants golf code, but only to make it a little bit more readable !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is by using the operator XOR (operator.xor):

let's suppose:

```
# A: 'pro' in application_id

# B: main_service_id == 102
```

What you have is :

```
# (A.(not B)) + (B.(not A))
# Equivalent to A XOR B

if (('pro' in application_id) and (main_service_id != 102)) or  (('pro' not in application_id) and (main_service_id == 102)):
    return True
```

Would be:

```
if ('pro' in application_id)^(main_service_id == 102):
    return True
```

Or even:

```
if ('pro' in application_id)!=(main_service_id == 102):
    return True
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the xor operator.

`('pro' in application_id) != (main_service_id == 102)`

Comment: != (not equals) is not the XOR operator. The XOR operator is ^. Think of 5!=2. The result is true and not the XOR result (5^2=7). Reduced to booleans the != (not equals) operator produces the same output as the XOR operator. But it's still the *not equals* operator.

Answer (score 1):

This is a binary equation.
Let's define

```
p = 'pro' in application_id
m = main_service_id == 102
```

Then the if looks like this

```
if ((p && !m) || (!p && m))
```

It's simple to see that this is a XOR gate. So you can write

```
if (('pro' in application_id) ^ (main_service_id == 102))
```

Answer (score 1):

what about:

```
if ('pro' in application_id) != (main_service_id == 102):
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are using XOR operation if you convert the conditions into form of boolean and from them to 0 and 1
So simple the XOR operator is equal to `!=`
Just use `!=`

```
if condition1 != condition2:
     return True
```